# Contrasting Status Bar Text/Icon Colors (iOS13/Xcode11)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode11

I'm seeing a lot of conflicting sources, and their solutions are always involving deprecated keywords that no longer work either in iOS 13, XCode 11, or both.  My simulated iPhone is running iOS 13.6 and my XCode is version 11.6.

I've made it so that the navigation bar title and buttons take on a contrasting color (white or black) to the background color.  I'd like to make the status bar text and symbols (the wifi, clock, battery icon, etc.) take on the same appearance depending on the background.  Is there a way to do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller (aka hosting controller for SwiftUI), override the [`preferredStatusBarStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) variable. For example:

```swift
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```